# How to remove supposedly deleted font files in Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts

I deleted thousands of fonts with Bitstream Font Navigator. I thought it was working well, but what really happened was that it deleted only the registry entries, while keeping the font files in C:\Windows\Fonts.

Now my Windows installation is messed up, as fonts installed through that app are a simple link to a network folder, and fonts deleted are still kept in the folder.

Is there a program that does *simple* cross-checking between the registry and the fonts folder, deleting unregistered files?

Answer (score 3):

Open your Fonts folder in a classic view (as a network folder, Windows won't switch the view in that case), select all fonts and *Install* them from the context menu. That way you'll restore missing registry entries. Then remove fonts you don't need anymore. Maybe not the fastest way to do it, but should work.

Comment: I thought to do this way, but I would have to manually delete 1200 fonts... :(